# How to make while loop check if there are 16 digits in a string

Tags: java, string, while-loop, string-length

How do I make the loop check if there is 16 digits in a string and reset the string if there is not enough. I am trying to make a credit card program that will calculate the check digit. I have everything else working I just cant get the program to check the number of digits in the user inputted string.Thanks for any and all help!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LuhnAlgorithm {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number credit card number (Enter a blank line to quit: ");
        String nums = input.nextLine();

        int i = 0;
        char chk = nums.charAt(15);

        while(!nums .equals("") ) {

            if (nums.length()<16 || nums.length() > 15){ //How do I get this line to reset the while loop?
                System.out.println("ERROR! Number MUST have exactly 16 digits.");
            }

            int sum = 0;
            for( i = 0; i < 15; i++) {  
                char numc = nums.charAt(i);
                int num = Character.getNumericValue(numc);
                if ( i % 2 == 0 ) {
                    num = num * 2;
                    if ( num >= 10) {
                        num = num - 9;
                    }
                }
                sum = num + sum;
            }

            int sum2 = sum % 10;
            if (sum2 > 0) {
                sum2 = 10 - sum2;
            }
            int chk2 = Character.getNumericValue(chk);
            System.out.println("The check digit should be: " + sum2);
            System.out.println("The check digit is: " + chk);
            if ( sum2 == chk2) {
                System.out.println("Number is valid.");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Number is not valid. ");
            }

            System.out.print("Enter a number credit card number (Enter a blank line to quit:) ");
            nums = input.nextLine();
        }

        System.out.println("Goodbye!"); 
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why? Why not just test `nums.length() == 16`?

Comment: I am sorry I am new to coding. Do you mean in the while loop? while(nums.length() == 16 + !nums .equals(""))

Comment: what do you mean by "reset the while loop?"

Comment: also if something has a length of 16, you already know it's not ""

Comment: I need it to print out the error message then continue running the loop until it gets a accurate number of digits. In this case the number of digits required is 16.

Comment: Oh, now I follow you. Put the prompt at the top of the while loop. If it comes back "", brak. If it comes back length != 16, continue

Comment: Your first if statement checks if the length < 16 or if it is > 15. If it's exactly 16 characters long you will mistakenly mark it as wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include your code that you only want done if the `length ==16` in an if statement.

Meaning, instead of:

```
if (nums.length != 16) {
    //code if there is an error
}
//code if there is no error
```

you can do:

```
if (nums.length == 16) {
    //code if there is no error
} else {
    //code if there is an error
}
```

(I also want to point out that you set `chk = nums.charAt(15)` before your while loop, but you don't reset it in the while loop for the next time the user inputs a new credit card number.)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can bring the prompts and all your initialization except the scanner itself into the while loop. Then if they say "", `break` to exit the loop. If they say a number that is too short or too long, say *continue* to go back to the prompting.
Thus:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Enter a number credit card number (Enter a blank line to quit: ");
            String nums = input.nextLine().trim();
            if (nums.length() == 0) {
                break; //exits while loop
            }
            if (nums.length() != 16) { //How do I get this line to reset the while loop?
                System.out.println("ERROR! Number MUST have exactly 16 digits.");
                continue; //goes back to the beginning right away
            }
            //still here, process the number
            char chk = nums.charAt(15);
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
                char numc = nums.charAt(i);
                int num = Character.getNumericValue(numc);
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    num = num * 2;
                    if (num >= 10) {
                        num = num - 9;
                    }
                }

                sum = num + sum;
            }

            int sum2 = sum % 10;
            if (sum2 > 0) {
                sum2 = 10 - sum2;
            }
            int chk2 = Character.getNumericValue(chk);
            System.out.println("The check digit should be: " + sum2);
            System.out.println("The check digit is: " + chk);
            if (sum2 == chk2) {
                System.out.println("Number is valid.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Number is not valid. ");
            }





        }


        System.out.println("Goodbye!");


        input.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me with my code. I ended up fixing it by add in a if statement and had the else run the rest of the code. I did not know about "Breaks" and "continue" I started looking them up and will use them in future code. Thanks for the information!